# Is the lvalue reference return of a member function of a temporary object a dangling reference?

Tags: c++, temporary-objects, dangling-pointer

There is a class `CBase`.

```
class CBase
{
    ...
    CBase &Create()
    {
        return *this;
    }
    ...
}
```

If I declare an lvalue reference and a pointer,

```
CBase &kk = CBase().Create();
CBase *pp = &( CBase().Create() );
```

is `kk` a dangling reference and is `pp` a dangling pointer?

I think `kk` and `pp` are dangling. Because calling `CBase()` creates a temporary object no doubt, the derivative, `CBase().Create()`, should be too. However, Xcode (version 6.1) gives no warning or error message.

Can anyone give some hints or tell me where the C++11 document describes these behaviors? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Of course it does not warn/error at compile-time. It does not know that `Create()` will return a reference to `*this` when called at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `kk` is a dangling reference and `pp` is a dangling pointer. The temporary produced by `CBase()` only exists for the duration of the full expression in which it appears. Note that it is still valid to have a pointer or reference refer to this object, as long as their lifetime is bound to the expression as well.

Since `kk` and `pp` still exist after the full expression, this is not the case. Using `kk` and dereferencing `pp` has undefined behavior.

Comment: question: if we'd have `const CBase &kk = CBase().Create();` instead - does `const` change anything here? Is it still dangling reference or `kk`'s life is prolongued now?